z-index not working for stacking a box element over text
I'm trying to make some text appear after an "artificial" loading screen. I tried using z-index to stack the loading screen on top of the text, so after it fades out you can see the text behind it, however said text doesn't stack and just appears next to it as it loads. How can I fix this?
<style>
.frontpage {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 10; 
  animation: fadeout 3s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 5s;
 }

h1 {
 font-size: 40px; 
 font-family: "Lucida Console"; 
 color: white ;
 text-align: center;
 
}


.loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  top: 45%;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; 
  border-top: 16px solid #9245ff; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite; }

.mainpage {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
}

</style>
<head>

<div class="frontpage">
<div class="loader"> </div>
</div>

<div class="mainpage">
  <h1>Test Title</h1>  
</div>

</head>


Not sure if I understood your problem and goal correctly but this snippet might help you:


    <style>
    .frontpage {
        background-color: black;
        position: relative;
        height: 100vh;
        animation: fadeout 3s linear forwards;
        animation-delay: 5s;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: "Lucida Console";
        color: gray;
        text-align: center;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
    }


    .loader {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-top: 16px solid #9245ff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }
</style>

<head>

    <div class="frontpage">
        <h1>Test Title</h1>
        <div class="loader"> </div>
    </div>


</head>



You probably don't need z-index for this case. It's best to avoid using it unless there is no other way. If the container position is relative, and the child item is position absolute, the items will stack up on top of each other, so this will make the loader appear on top of the header
<h1>Test Title</h1>
<div class="loader"> </div>

And this will put the header on top of the loader
<div class="loader"> </div>
<h1>Test Title</h1>


I looked over the snippet and edited some my script, and the text does stack! but it only stacks on top of the loading screen, not under it.

Stacking is controlled either by the order of how it's defined in your HTML, or by z-index. The z-index takes precedence. So if you remove z-index you should be able to control stacking with HTML only
